# Insert Row, Fill Down Formula - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have formulas in columns `I:N` and after inserting a new row, add a 2 to column G and copying the value in H i want to be able to fill down the formulas in `I:N` and `AJ:AP`.

This is what i have so far

```
Sub InsertRowAndFillDown(): Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = ActiveCell.Row

Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Long

' Insert Row
With ActiveCell
rw = .Row
.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
End With

' Add value 2 to column G
Set rng = Rows(rw + 1)
rng.Columns("G").FormulaR1C1 = "2"

' Copy value from cell above in column H
For i = 1 To 7
If i = 1 Then i = 8
Cells(j + 1, i) = Cells(j, i): Next i:

' Fill down columns I:N    

End Sub
```

I was using `Worksheets("MIDP + IRS").Range("I:N").FillDown` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub InsertRowAndFillDown()
    Dim rw As Range
    
    Set rw = ActiveCell.EntireRow 'the selected row
    rw.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    
    rw.Columns("G").Offset(1).Value = 2
    With rw.Columns("H")
        .Offset(1).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    'Range here is *relative* to `rw`
    rw.Range("I1:N2,AJ1:AP2").FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect and the first half is much cleaner too.